# BrowserStack Jenkins Pipeline AppUploader "File not found at" Error

Tags: android, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, browserstack

I'm trying to set up a basic BrowserStack sample App with Jenkins a Jenkinsfile for the Pipeline.

Reading the documentation of the BrowserStack plugin for Jenkins I came up with the following step:

```
// ...
stages {
    stage('assemble') {
        // Here the App gets assembled
    }

    stage('upload-to-browserstack'){
        steps{

            browserstack(credentialsId: '<credentials>'){
              sh 'test -e app/build/outputs/apk/flavorProduction/debug/browserstack-sample-debug.apk && echo exists || echo does not exist'

              browserstackAppUploader('app/build/outputs/apk/flavorProduction/debug/browserstack-sample-debug.apk'){

              }
            }
        }
    }
}
// ...
```

This results in the following error message:

```
[BrowserStack] Starting upload process.
[BrowserStack] Uploading app app/build/outputs/apk/flavorProduction/debug/browserstack-sample-debug.apk to Browserstack.
[BrowserStack] [ERROR] File not found at app/build/outputs/apk/flavorProduction/debug/browserstack-sample-debug.apk
[BrowserStack] ERROR : App Id empty. ABORTING!!!
```

I can see, that the file exists on my Jenkins instance. How can I upload the APK to the BrowserStack server or am I using a wrong syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the two scripts in your Jenkins build step in order to upload an app and use the hash ID from the response.

result="$(curl -u ":" -X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload" -F "file=@/Users/Downloads/BStackSampleApp_1.ipa" | jq -r '.app_url')"

result="$(curl -u ":" -X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload" -F "file=@/Users/Downloads/BStackSampleApp_1.ipa" | jq '.app_url' | tr -d \")"

You can then export the value of the result as the environment variable for the Jenkins configuration.

Comment: This is for using the REST API of BrowserStack. I would like to use the Jenkins Plugin of BrowserStack, so I don't have to expose the Access Key in the Jenkinsfile. Or can I use this inside the `browserstack(){}` block without hardcoding the credentials?